# Meteor and Ipinfo : return ip off my server

Tags: meteor

I use ipInfo for get the user ip on my Meteor APP. On local dev, ipInfo return good data : my ip.

But on my production server, ipInfo return ip off my server and not ip client :

```
import { HTTP } from 'meteor/http';

Meteor.methods({
  getIp: function() {
    let request  = Meteor.wrapAsync(HTTP.get),
        result = request('http://ipinfo.io');
        console.log(result); // Good on local, but only server IP on production
    return result;
  }
});
```

Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to call ipInfo from client side.

If you want to call it from server...well... use [onConnection](http://docs.meteor.com/api/connections.html#Meteor-onConnection) functions to get client IP and when ask ipInfo

If you call server-side method from client, you can use `this.connection.clientAddress` too....

Comment: Hi :) I've test `this.connection.clientAddress` but i've undefined error. Maybe i need import module ?

Comment: I've add  `console.log(this.connection.clientAddress);` to my method and it's working...I didn't add anything more

Comment: From the client or from the server ?

Comment: Absolutely on server: http://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#DDPCommon-MethodInvocation-connection

And, of course, you have to look server console

Comment: Yes, i've test on server and on my server console `Exception while invoking method 'getIp' TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientAddress' of undefined`

Comment: Very, very strange... well try to simply `console.log(this)`

Comment: Ok, now it work (after adding before my wraAsync). But this return 127.0.0.1, not the user ip ?

Comment: If you call method from local PC - address will be 127.0.0.1

Comment: Okey, i think it's good. I use Nginx on my server, do you think i need to add HTTP_FORWARDED_COUNT to 1 ? (from doc)

Comment: I think - yes. But you have to check (-:

Comment: After deploying, i confirm : i need to add `HTTP_FORWARDED_COUNT` :) Thank again ;)

Comment: Cool!

But again: it is bad idea to get client info on server method. 1000 clients will create 1000 requests from your server... too bad. But 1000 clients will create 1000 requests from 1000 different computers, not from one server.. Think about this situation..

Comment: Yes, but i can't call my clientAdress on client, i need to be on server :( I'll look to do as you say. Thanks again !